# I want to change the audio and zoom x1.2 from the input video from my code. I have tried it but it failed

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to change the audio and zoom x1.2 from the input video from my code. I have tried it but it failed. We hope to help. Here is my code: (sorry i am not good at english so i use google translate)

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i image1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i image2.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:1.0:1.0[fg];[0][fg]overlay=shortest=1[bg1];[bg1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[bg2];[bg2][3]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale):

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -y -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i image1.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i image2.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:1.0:1.0[fg];[0]scale=iw*1.2:ih*1.2[bg0];[bg0][fg]overlay=shortest=1[bg1];[bg1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1[bg2];[bg2][3]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: tks llogan very much